# Aligning nodes which are connected between each other in NS2

Tags: ns2

I'm trying to align the nodes that I created as in the picture in network simulator 2 but something is wrong in the code that I wrote. How can I place the nodes as in this picture?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nob4G.jpg)

**Codes:**

```
set ns [new Simulator]
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]

$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n1 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n3 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n2 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n4 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n3 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n2 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n4 orient left
$ns duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 orient left
$ns duplex-link-op $n1 $n3 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n4 $n2 orient right-down

proc finish {} {
    global ns nf
    $ns flush-trace
    close $nf
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}

$ns at 1.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scenario generators like NSG2 to create your own topologies. download NSG2 form [here](http://www.techerina.com/2015/02/nsg2-script-generator-tool-for-generating-tcl-script.html)
Note that you must install java on your linux machine before running NSG2 .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Your uploaded image is not available. I understand from the code you have written, so if you want to create a network topology like in the attached screenshot, you can edit your code as follows.

```
set ns [new Simulator]
set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]

# Create Links between nodes
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n2 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link $n3 $n4 1Mb 10ms DropTail

# Orientation of Nodes in Topology
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n1 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n3 orient left-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n2 orient right-down
$ns duplex-link-op $n0 $n4 orient left-down



proc finish {} {
    global ns nf
    $ns flush-trace
    close $nf
    exec nam out.nam &
    exit 0
}

$ns at 1.0 "finish"
$ns run
```

[Aligned_Network Topology_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG7uO.png)
[Aligned_Network_Topology_2](https://imge.to/i/GBC2V)